# Sass::SyntaxError in Pages#home

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to import bootstrap, rails server not realizing I updated my code

**localhost:3000**

```
Sass::SyntaxError in Pages#home
Showing C:/Users/Victor/sampleapp/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #6 raised:

File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap.
Load paths:
  C:/Users/Victor/sampleapp/app/assets/images
  C:/Users/Victor/sampleapp/app/assets/javascripts
  C:/Users/Victor/sampleapp/app/assets/stylesheets
  C:/Users/Victor/sampleapp/vendor/assets/javascripts
  C:/Users/Victor/sampleapp/vendor/assets/stylesheets
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jquery-rails-3.0.4/vendor/assets/javascripts
  (in C:/Users/Victor/sampleapp/app/assets/stylesheets/styles.css.scss:1)
Extracted source (around line #6):
```

I tired restarting the server by using *rails s* in the terminal. But I still get the same `Sass::SyntaxError`

Comment: Can you post `app/assets/stylesheets/styles.css.scss`? It says the error is with line 1.

Comment: Do you have bootstrap file in one of the folders listed under an error?

Comment: Can you try putting `@import 'bootstrap'` in `app/assets/stylesheets/application.sass`?

Comment: @JasonKim i didn't work